# Bazel, protobuf 3.6.1.3, -Wall, and an unhappy gcc 9.1.1

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, bazel

Is there a way to pass compiler options to protocol buffer libraries in Bazel?

In my Bazel C++ project, I'm compiling everything with `-Wall`, and after upgrading to C++ I'm running into problems with GCC 9.1.1 and protobufs.

GCC is upset with some of the members in the generated protobuf code, because of the generated code calls `memset` with values that reach outside the bounds of the referenced subobjects. I'd like to add `-Wno-array-bounds` to remove the warning, but ONLY for the protobuf code. The Bazel `cc_proto_library` rule doesn't provide any way to pass options to the compiler -- is there another way to do this?

Comment: compile with `-Wno-format-extra-args`

Comment: I still get the errors about the memset calls if I do that.

Comment: please show us the `memset()` is called